# IndexError with list in Python

Tags: python

I have a function which takes 2 arguments - an input string, and a list of words. For every word in the list which is present in the string, the function returns "True", else "False".

My code is given below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


# inputStr is a string, inputList is  list of strings

def keyword_usage(inputStr, inputList):

    splitStr = inputStr.split();
    L = [];
    k = 0;
    bool = 0;

    for i in range(0,len(inputList)):

        for  j in range(0, len(inputStr)):

            if inputList[i]==splitStr[j]:
                bool = 1;
            else:
                bool = 0;
        if bool==1:
            L[k] = "True";
        else:
            L[k] = "False";
        k+=1;
    return tuple(L);
```

I am running it in the interpreter as shown below:

```
>>> from keyword_usage import keyword_usage
>>> res = keyword_usage('Dive  Into  Python',  ['Python',  'python', 'scala'])
```

When I press enter, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "keyword_usage.py", line 17, in keyword_usage
    if inputList[i]==splitStr[j]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am new to Python coding and am very confused. It seems a basic question, but I could not get any answer on any forum. Can someone spot the error? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
def keyword_usage(inputStr, inputList):
    splitStr = inputStr.split();
    L = []
    b = False
    for i in range(0,len(inputList)):
        for  j in range(0, len(inputStr)):
            b = inputList[i]==splitStr[j]
        L.append(b)
    return tuple(L)

print keyword_usage('Dive  Into  Python',  ['Python',  'python', 'scala'])
```

You made a lot of mistakes:

- Python doesn't use ';'
- Don't use 0 or 1 as boolean but use True and False instead.
- Now you can save True or False in that boolean
- In the seccond loop, I think you ment splitStr instead of inputList

And the error was caused by:

```
L[k] = "True";
```

Since L has no items yet, you can't add items that way. Use append instead:

```
L.append("True")
```

Ouput now:

```
(True, False, False)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and information! Actually I had added the ";" because of the errors I kept getting, and yes, I meant splitStr.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a more pythonic solution:

```
def keyword_usage(inputStr, inputList):
    splitStr = inputStr.split()
    L = []
    for i in inputList:
        L.append(i in splitStr)
    return tuple(L)
```

That's it!

Use the `in` operator. It checks if an element is present in a list and returns `True` or `False`.

```
'Dive' in ['Python', 'python', 'scala']
>>> False
'Python' in ['Python', 'python', 'scala']
>>> True
```

Comment: Thank you too for this information, I didn't know it could be that simple!

Comment: Now you know. Python is that simple and elegant, but it takes time to get enlightened with the wisdom :)

Answer (score 1):

And let's take it one step beyond. Learn to know the comprehension lists:

```
def keyword_usage(inputStr, inputList):
    splitStr = inputStr.split()
    L = [i in splitStr for i in inputList]
    return tuple(L)
```

Now you can run the function:

```
keyword_usage('Dive Into Python', ['Python', 'python', 'scala'])
>>> (True, False, False)
```

But I would extend the function even on step further:

```
def keyword_usage(inputStr, inputList):
    splitStr = inputStr.split()
    L = [i in splitStr for i in inputList]
    return dict(zip(inputList, L))
```

Now you have this result:

```
keyword_usage('Dive Into Python', ['Python', 'python', 'scala'])
>>> {'Python': True, 'python': False, 'scala': False}
```

So you know immediately which list element was found in the string.

You can rewrite the list comprehension like this:

```
L = [(i in splitStr) for i in inputList]
```

for better readability, if you like it more.

The built-in function `zip` combines two lists together, first element of list A with the first element of list B, second element of list A with the second element of list B, and so on. The built-in function `dict` then makes a nice dictionary of these values.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like just a typo.

This:

```
for  j in range(0, len(inputStr)):
```

Should be this:

```
for j in range(0, len(splitStr)):
```

Answer (score 0):

`print len(splitStr)`

gives :- `3`

```
print len(inputList), len(inputStr)
```

gives:- `3`, `18`

when you check

```
if inputList[i]==splitStr[j] #for i = 1 and j = 12
```

while `splitStr` just have three values  `['Dive', 'Into', 'Python']`

when you run `for  j in range(0, len(inputStr))` it will loop for 18 times anf every time `j` takes values from (0,18) so it checks for `splitStr[j]` let's say 10 then `splitStr[10]` which is actually (`['Dive', 'Into', 'Python']`) out of range.